# Failure default param in UnitTests

Tags: c++, objective-c, clang, default-parameters

In my project I have two files `Products.h` and `.m`. If I build project and run, I dont get any warnings & errors.

But when I run tests. I catch an error on this piece of source code:

```
NSArray* fetchItem(NSString* entity, NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = nil);
```

The error message:

> "Clang does not support default params".

Ok, I know, it may be a problem due to the architecture of the project.

I change the architecture in UnitTest as MainProject from `$(ARCHS_STANDART_32BIT)` to `$(ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONEOS)`. 
And all the same catch error

> "Expected ';' ',' or ')' before '=' token.

In both projects ARC is off.

So essentially, my question is, "How to enable default params on UnitTest projects?" Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code line pls check if u r missing assignment

```
NSArray* fetchItem = (NSString* entity, NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = nil);
```

I dont know what you want, coz after assignment that line is not making me any sense.

Comment: This declaration of method on C++. That not declare variable. I need just declare method and then implement him.

Comment: exactly, i was sure that it isn't to declare variable. Thats why I wrote that 'it dont make me any sense'. Is that line to declare a method.? I'll see if I could help u to enable default params on UnitTest project?

Comment: Yes, that string for method declare.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer. Use default parameters bad syntax and not usage in Objective-C, I remove default param and problem solved.